# Is execute permisson required in uploading file by scp?

Tags: linux, centos

I created a web application directory and app in the directory.
And, they have 776 permission and their group is apache:apache.

I'd like to allow others to upload modules by scp.
But,I want others not to execute programs.So,I don't give "x" others , but it doesn't work. They cant upload file and permisson denied.others group is "xxx".
I think if others have read and write permission , they can upload file. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add files to a directory you need both write (+w) and execute (+x) permissions.

See this answer for how file permissions work in Linux:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/execute-vs-read-bit-how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work

The execute permission on a directory does not imply files in that directory are made executable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I didn't understand the difference between directory permissions  and file permission.